# How do I perform a code action on a visual range in Neovim 0.9?

Tags: neovim, lsp

In Neovim 0.8, I had the following command mapped

`vnoremap <leader>a :lua vim.lsp.buf.range_code_action()<cr>`

which in visual mode, gave me options such as Wrap In Try-Catch/Extract Method etc.

Now in 0.9 `range_code_action` no longer exists and https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html#vim.lsp.buf.code_action() says "range: (table|nil) Range for which code actions should be requested. If in visual mode this defaults to the active selection."

I've tried simply changing the mapping to `lua vim.lsp.buf.range_code_action()` but I'm just getting the basic code actions, not the various Wrap/Extract method etc.

I'm coding Dart.

Any ideas how I a get my range code actions back?

Comment: It's possible that it's not triggering the automatic handling of a range from Visual mode because when you use `:` you're actually switching to command-line mode. Try using `<Cmd>` to run the `:lua` command without switching to command-line mode from your mapping, such as `vnoremap <leader>a <Cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<cr>`. See [`:help <Cmd>`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/map.html#%3CCmd%3E) for more details.

Comment: @filbranden thnx for the suggestion, but still the same

Comment: @filbranden on regressing to nvim 0.8 and implementing your suggestion, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`vnoremap <leader>la :lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>`

Reference: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/19551

Comment: You probably meant `:xnoremap` unless NeoVim removed that